# ISAPI Extensions in IIS 6.0 VS IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, asp-classic

I am a newbie to ASP.NET Development.
I would like to know how the dependency on ISAPI is reduced from IIS 7.0.

If I am not wrong, Until IIS 6.0 the Classic ASP and ASP.NET are implemented as ISAPI Extensions in the IIS. I am curious to know how this scenario is changed from IIS 7.0.
It would be more helpful, if some links and block diagrams are provided with necessary explanations.

Comment: Not sure much has changed `Classic ASP` is still an `ISAPI` Module as is `ASP.Net`. The difference with IIS 7+ is the modular approach to the configuration and features.